# format numbers to 4 digits in Azure Pipline

Tags: yaml, azure-pipelines

I try to format 4 digits in `Azure` pipeline (`YAML`) but its not working, someone help?

i have this variable >> serialNumber: 2

I used the following `yaml` syntax:

```
formatnumber: $[format('{0:D4}', variables.serialNumber)]

formatnumber: $[format('{0:0000}', variables.serialNumber)]

formatnumber: $[format('{0:####}', variables.serialNumber)]
```

i want to convert the number 2 to 0002 with format but i get the following error:

> An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The format specifiers 'D4' are not valid for objects of type 'String'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above formater doesnot work is because the type of the value returned by variables.serialNumber is string not int type.

There is a workaround to achieve this. You can add a powershell task to format the number. You can check below example.

```
trigger:
- master
variables:
  number: 2
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
steps:
- powershell: |
    $number = $(number)
    $format = "{0:0000}" -f $number
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=formatnumber]$format"

- powershell: echo "$(formatnumber)"
```

Above script in powershell task formats the variable `number`, and [set the formatted number to variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-in-script) 'formatnumber'. Then the following task can refer to the formatted number by `$(formatnumber)`